# Best practice: functions within loops

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I got the following code which works perfectly. What it does is: in a table it highlights the corresponding table header cell and table first column cell when you hover over any table cell.

```
  // Row & Column Highlight
 (function() {

     var gridCellRow = null,
         gridCellCol = null,
         tableElement = document.getElementsByClassName('inner_table');
     for (var i = 0, len_i = tableElement.length; i < len_i; i++) {
         if (tableElement[i].getElementsByClassName('row_label_cell').length > 0) {
             var gridCell = tableElement[i].getElementsByClassName('input_cell');
             for (var j = 0, len_j = gridCell.length; j < len_j; j++) {
                 function gridCellParents(currentCell) {
                     return gridCellRow = currentCell.parentNode.firstElementChild,
                         gridCellCol = currentCell.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].cells[currentCell.cellIndex];
                 }
                 gridCell[j].addEventListener('mouseover', (function() {
                     gridCellParents(this);
                     gridCellRow.classList.add('highlight');
                     gridCellCol.classList.add('highlight');
                 }));
                 gridCell[j].addEventListener('mouseout', (function() {
                     gridCellRow.classList.remove('highlight');
                     gridCellCol.classList.remove('highlight');
                 }));
             }
         }
     }

 }());
```

However, JSHint tells me, that

```
for (var j = 0, len_j = gridCell.length; j < len_j; j++) {
 function gridCellParents(currentCell) {
     return gridCellRow = currentCell.parentNode.firstElementChild,
         gridCellCol = currentCell.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].cells[currentCell.cellIndex];
 }
```

is not best practice *"Function declarations should not be placed in blocks. Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function."*

as well as

```
gridCell[j].addEventListener('mouseover', (function() {
gridCellParents(this);
gridCellRow.classList.add('highlight');
gridCellCol.classList.add('highlight');
}));
gridCell[j].addEventListener('mouseout', (function() {
    gridCellRow.classList.remove('highlight');
    gridCellCol.classList.remove('highlight');
}));
}
```

is not best practice *"Don't make functions within a loop."*

So how am I correctly and according to best practice building this whole function?

Comment: so take it out of the loop, what's the problem? of course it shouldn't be in a loop! does it makes sense to create the exact same function over and over again? a little common sense ;)

Comment: So move the function declaration outside the loop.

Comment: I know that does not make sense, that's why I'm asking for advice and a little example on how to build this the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Function deceleration shouldn't be within loops because it makes no
>   sense to re-create the same function over and over again, in a
>   "continuous flow" (unlike other situation where the same function
>   might be created again, in a more complex code). The main reason is
>   because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) and it strongly goes against javascript
>   principles to write functions declarations inside loops.

A good starting point, with a more ordered code:

```
     // Row & Column Highlight
(function() {
    var gridCellRow,
        gridCellCol,
        gridCell,
        tableElement = document.getElementsByClassName('inner_table');   

    function gridCellParents(currentCell) {
        gridCellRow = currentCell.parentNode.firstElementChild,
        gridCellCol = currentCell.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].cells[currentCell.cellIndex];
    }

    function onMouseEnter() {
        gridCellParents(this);
        gridCellRow.classList.add('highlight');
        gridCellCol.classList.add('highlight');
    }

    function onMuoseLeave() {
        gridCellRow.classList.remove('highlight');
        gridCellCol.classList.remove('highlight');
    }


    for (var i = 0, len_i = tableElement.length; i < len_i; i++) {
        if (tableElement[i].getElementsByClassName('row_label_cell').length > 0) {
            gridCell = tableElement[i].getElementsByClassName('input_cell');                    
            for (var j = 0, len_j = gridCell.length; j < len_j; j++) {
                gridCell[j].addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnter);
                gridCell[j].addEventListener('mouseleave', onMuoseLeave);
            }
        }
}}());
```

As you can see, I've modified your events to [mousenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) which might better suit your needs and be better for overall performance.

---

### Update - delegated version:

```
 // Row & Column Highlight
(function() {
    var gridCell,
        tableElement = document.querySelectorAll('.inner_table');   

    function getCellParents(cell){
        return {
            row : cell.parentNode.firstElementChild,                       // row
            col : cell.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].cells[cell.cellIndex] // col
       }; 
    }

    function updateGridCellParents(cell, state) {
        state = state ? 'add' : 'remove';

        var parents = getCellParents(cell);

        parents.row.classList[state]('highlight');
        parents.col.classList[state]('highlight');
    }

    funciton checkTarget(target){
        // make sure the element is what we expected it to be
        return target.className.indexOf('input_cell') != 0;
    }

    function onMouseEvents(e){
        checkTarget(e.target) && updateGridCellParents(e.target, e.type == "mouseover");
    }

    document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseEvents);
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseEvents);
})();
```

Comment: great thanks. that looks reasonable to me. Is it in any way possible to call onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave as anonymous functions?

Comment: @sangrilaB I've modified the code to be even more logical, so now there is a single function called `toggleHighlight`. ok?

Comment: @vsync: the better it gets, the more can I learn. Please do so.

Comment: it can get crazy better :)

Comment: I'm really curious. If you got any futher hints on improving this, please share with me. I'm thankful for getting to know new things.

Comment: It also depends on which browsers you want to support (many improvements won't work on IE9 and below for example. maybe not even on 10 and 11). Also using jQuery might make the code shorter and more readable. But it would only make sense to use jQuery if you have lots of DOM-related code.

Comment: regarding browser support: I need IE9 and upwards (plus Android 4.0 and upwards, iOS 6 and upwards). I know that jQuery is more efficient but I need to stick to vanilla js for this one.

Comment: @sangrilaB -  I've made an updated version using [event-delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) method. Code wasn't tested because I don't have any HTML to test this on.

Comment: (Temporarily) downvoted because you don't explain why it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer, I think it is important to also state **why** it is a bad practice.

The issue when creating functions inside loops is that they often use values that depends on the loop's iteration. Let's have an example.

```js
// Create three function, that writes their number
var funcs = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  funcs.push(function(){
    document.write(i);
  });
}

// Call them.
funcs.forEach(function(f){
  f();
});
```

One may expect the above code to write 1 then 2 then 3. However, because variables in JS are not block-scoped but function-scoped (except for the new `let` and `const`), the closure of all three of these functions will actually use the exact same `i`: 3, the last value it had been given (and thus the value it still has).

Because of this behaviour, this is very easy to make mistakes. Hence, it is not recommended.

If you need to create a function that depends of the value of a loop, you can use a factory.

```js
// Create a factory function that returns a
// function that writes the argument.
function writerFactory(msg){
  return function(){
    document.write(msg);
  }
}

// Create three functions, that write their number.
var funcs = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  funcs.push(writerFactory(i));
}

// Call them.
funcs.forEach(function(f){
  f();
});
```

This time, each function has a different closure: the one that is created by each call of the factory. They all have access to a different `msg`.

Comment: It's also kinda expensive to evaluate/create the function each iteration through the loop.  It's cheaper to just create the function once.

Comment: This is true. Though you have to loop a lot to see the difference. I would not worry too much about this most of the time. Readability first.